# Which form of data analysis would be most appropriate, T-Test or Chi-Squared?

Tags: chi-squared-test, t-test

I have 2 areas within the UK, Oswestry and Swansea, which I have got the crime data figures for for my Geography dissertation... I need to compare the two areas to see the difference in crime... I have 24 crime figures from Oswestry, and 36 from Swansea.
Which would be the best way to do this (I am using SPSS) - Chi-Squared or an Independent T-Test?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: In addition to @Michelle's questions, I'd ask:  Are these 24 and 36 exhaustive, or samples from the total number of such figures for, say, the year?  If the former, are you trying to use this year's data to generalize about other years (or next year)?  It's not obvious to me that a statistical *test* is what you need.

Comment: Are these a time series (e.g. 36 months), in which case we're going to have autocorrelation issues, or are they different districts, in which case we may (or may not) have spatial correlation issues?

Answer (score 3):

Do you only have one set of crime figures per area? Are the crime figures counts of crimes, e.g. the number of burglaries committed? Also, as per comments above, what question are you trying to answer with the data? Sometimes the research question and the available data are not compatible.

Updated response based on new information:
Based on your data below, it sounds like you want the Chi-Squared test, as you have counts. You sound like you have a 2xMany table (2 Districts{1} x many crimes). This advice is based on the idea that you only have counts of reported crimes and not actual crimes, and you want to comment on the differences of actual crime counts.

If you just wish to look at reported crimes, don't do any statistics and report the difference in the figures. We use statistics to infer from a sample to a population, and if you're only interested in reported crimes, then you have the population information and there is nothing to infer.

{1} Assuming those two locations you mention are Districts.

Update based on comment: If you are looking at differences in reported crime for that 12-month period, you don't need to do any statistics - you have all the information about reported crime so any differences you see are "real" differences. This is the point that rolando2 was making in his comment - you only use statistics if you don't have all the data. I'm guessing that you want to know if the differences between the Swansea and Oswestry are important. This can be the hardest question of all - when do I care about the differences in results - when the counts are 1 different, or 10 different, or 1000 different? And that's the judgement call we all end up making. This is the "practical significance" of the results, and statistics cannot help you with this. You need to define difference in a way that makes sense with the way the data is generated.

Update 2: it would make sense to examine the figures as differences in rates, rather than differences in raw counts, if you haven't already thought of doing this. Using rates, e.g. burglary rate per 1000 households means that you get a better picture of the level of crime between the two places. For example, if one of the places has more residential dwellings than the other, you might expect there would be more residential burglaries. Confirming that on the basis of counts would not be very informative.

Comment: Well, I have the crime figures for all crimes (a sum of burglaries, muggings, theft of car, from car, etc) over a 12 month period from 3 areas in Swansea and 2 in Oswestry. But I'm not comparing those three areas individually, but a sum of them to compare the two places rather than areas. The only reason there are 3 and 2 is because that's how many policing districts there are in each place that I'm looking at. And I am looking at comparing Oswestry and Swansea crime figures as a whole to see if  there is a statistically significant difference?

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost in complete agreeement with @Michelle's answer.  I'd modify it slightly, in light of your original post + comments, to recommend that you do a *Z*-test of the difference between proportions.  As she said, you can use rate per 1000 or some similar indicator.  And since you're averaging the 2 or 3 results within each district and summing across all the different types of crimes you're tracking, you end up with one proportion for each district, as in  a/1000 vs. b/1000.  That difference is what would be most convenient to test.  If you prefer Chi-Square, you'd use a 2x2 table populated by a, 1000-a, b, and 1000-b.  Either of these tests will give equivalent results, but the former will give you the chance to construct a confidence interval for the difference.

You asked about SPSS procedures:  I wouldn't try to do either using SPSS.  It'll be easier to use an online calculator.